# Script fails to fetch all the names available in a link

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to fetch the names of all the hostels available in the following link. The thing is the names are generated dynamically and that is reason I can't grab them using `get` requests. However, when I issue a `post` requests with appropriate payload then I can fetch the name from it's landing page. Trouble comes up when i click on the `show more records` button as I can see an extra field `'lr': '87'` in payload is being added and I can't manage to use that in the right way.

[Website address](http://hosteldunia.com/search?address=hyderabad)

The numbers incremented when i click on the `show more records` button are like `87`,`227`,`384`,`457` and so on.

Here is what I've tried to parse the content (working one for first few names):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://hosteldunia.com/controller/search2.php'

payload={
    'address': 'hyderabad',
    'forWhom': 'Men',
    'accomodationType': 'undefined',
    'min': '2000',
    'max': '20000',
    'filter': 'single|doubleShare|tripleShare|fourShare|fiveShare'
}
session = requests.Session()
r = session.post(url,data=payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
for item in soup.select("h5.hover-title-top"):
    print(item.text)
```

***How can i get all the names from that link using requests?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proved to be some challenge, I had to look in the javascript code to find this out.

The response contains a single div with class 'more', its id is the next lr. I bet they don't have code reviews :)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



def get_next_batch(lr):
    url = 'http://hosteldunia.com/controller/search2.php'

    payload = {
        'address': 'hyderabad',
        'forWhom': 'Men',
        'accomodationType': 'undefined',
        'min': '2000',
        'max': '20000',
        'filter': 'single|doubleShare|tripleShare|fourShare|fiveShare',
        'lr': lr
    }
    session = requests.Session()
    r = session.post(url, data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    for item in soup.select("h5.hover-title-top"):
        print(item.text)

    next_lr = soup.select(".more")[0]['id']
    return next_lr

lr = None
#loads next batches
lr = get_next_batch(lr)
lr = get_next_batch(lr)
lr = get_next_batch(lr)
```

Comment: Awesomely nice approach @Borislav Stoilov!!! It worked perfectly. I've a quick little question- why doesn't the `next_lr` update when I try [like this](https://pastebin.com/QizwS5zh). Any comment on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You were creating the payload object on each iteration and you were losing the lr, and each time called the endpoint with the same lr.
https://pastebin.com/tQsKCDD7 do it like this :)